# Rewrite rule Mod_Proxy truncate file name

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewrite, mod-proxy

I search online for the solution, but nothing :(.

I write this simple rule

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [P,NE,QSA,L]
```

In mysite.it i have an .htaccess with this rule and it's ok, but if i have a link

"http://www.mysite.it/public/file name.html"

the server point to "http://www.mysite.it/public/file"

I try many solution but i can't solve.

I try this and many shades of...

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)(%20)(.*)$ "http://www.mysite.com/$1$3" [P,NE,QSA,L]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does it work without the [P]? Ie, does `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http://www.mysite.com/$1 [NE,QSA,L]"` work? If so, there's an issue with mod_proxy not mod_rewrite.

Comment: Thanks. Yes without mod_proxy [P] it's ok, but how i can without rewrite?

Comment: I don't think this question is a duplicate, so (in my opinion) it's been unfairly marked as such. The problem is quite subtle: a rewrite rule that uses the [P] flag doesn't handle spaces in filenames nicely. The linked question only has this to say about the [P] flag: "This is a dangerous flag, as a poorly written one will turn your web-server into an open-proxy and That is Bad". Maybe the [P] flag is wrong in this case, but I don't see that the question deserves to be marked as a duplicate. I can't solve it, sadly.

Comment: No one knows anything?